# Como mostrar a data/hora em um janela modal?

Tags: c#, modal

Estou com um código abaixo mas gostaria de exibir a data/hora em  uma caixa de mensagem  modal.

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");       
        Console.WriteLine("agora são: "+DateTime.Now.ToString());       
        var hstr = DateTime.Now.Minute;
        if (hstr > (30)) {
            Console.WriteLine("agora são: "+DateTime.Now.Hour+1);       
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.Hour+":00");
            Console.WriteLine(": "+DateTime.Now.Minute);        
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Caso seja uma Console Application foge do escopo do tipo de projeto nesse caso é recomendada a  utilização de um projeto WPF ou WinForms.

Comment: @davidterra Não mesmo. Um projeto WinForms ou WPF nada mais é do que um "console application" que referencia algumas DLL's.

Answer (score 3):

Você precisa preparar seu projeto para que tenha os recursos necessários para chamar a caixa de mensagem.

Sua aplicação do tipo "Console Application" não contém a DLL `System.Windows.Forms`, portanto, você precisa importá-la para seu projeto.

1. Ir no menu projeto e a clicar em adicionar referência
   [image: Menu projeto - adicionar referencia]
2. Escolher nesta listagem pela guia Assemblies a DLL chamada `System.Windows.Forms`
   [image: Importação da DLL Windows.Forms]
3. Adicionar no código o `using` desta DLL para permitir utilizar o método `MessageBox`
   `using System.Windows.Forms;`
4. Chamar o `MessageBox` com seu texto
   `MessageBox.Show("agora são: " + DateTime.Now.ToString(), "Data/hora atual");`

Answer (score -1):

Só pra mostrar uma mensagem num diálogo modal é assim:

```
MessageBox.Show(mensagem);
```